# Tag a commit in Xcode

Tags: git, tags, xcode6

Is there any way how to create a tag for specific commit in Xcode? Is there any support for git tags? I can see just branch stuff (new, switch, merge) under Source Control.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Three years after, **Xcode 9** has been enhanced by tagging feature. Just go to Source Control navigator and tag any commit via context menu opened by rightclicking that specific commit.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported in Xcode6. Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEe1Ul0bHko or show this plugin https://github.com/wczekalski/WCGitTagsPlugin